# Javascript onclick prompt save value

Tags: javascript, php, alert, prompt, setcookie

First of all I am displaying some text on my page for the user using php
If the cookie id name is not found it will display the text whats your name.

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
    echo $_COOKIE["name"];
}
else {
    echo "<a href='' onclick='setcookie()'>Whats your name</a>";
}
?>
```

Onclick i get the alert/prompt for the user to input their name.

Next i want to create a cookie, the id of the cookie is name and the value will be their name that was input into the alert/prompt.
I have been searching all day for away to do this but most explanations use a form input which i don't want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setcookie(name, value, expires) {
        var name=prompt("Please enter your name");        
    }       

</script>
```

Hopefully then if the cookie id name is found by php it will display the users name.

Comment: So where exactly are you sending the name back to the server?

Comment: Your function makes no sense. You have 3 parameters you send no values in, and then you reset one of those variables immediately with a prompt

Comment: Guys that's the whole point of asking the question I don't know what I am doing, I didn't find any help searching all day for an answer on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to set a cookie with JavaScript, [there's some docs for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).

For example, to set a cookie `name`:

```
document.cookie = 'name=' + name + '; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a cookie you can do the following

```
function setcookie() {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
    document.cookie = "name=" + name + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2014 12:00:00 GMT";
}
```

Like they said in the comments you have 3 parameters in your function which you don't send values for, I removed these value for this. If you need them to be passed from somewhere make sure you do so.